# Simple Duplication of several Machines (Imaging, with Linux)

Tags: linux, fedora, imaging

I have set up a single laptop (I have 10 of these exact models) for a demonstration next week. I want to copy the configuration (Fedora 13 with the software for demonstration) to the 9 other machines. Is this simply a dd operation? I may be thinking that I require more than what is really needed.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning linux to different machines (with different hardware configurations)](http://serverfault.com/questions/52314/cloning-linux-to-different-machines-with-different-hardware-configurations)

Comment: Cloning to a machine with the same HW is just a special case of cloning to different HW (and works the same). Hence the close vote :-).

Answer (score 2):

Clonezilla is what you need.
http://www.clonezilla.org

Answer (score 1):

Try [SystemImager](http://wiki.systemimager.org/index.php/Main_Page) - it will image and restore over a network, via PXE booting (or CDRom boot). Will work with different hardware, and you can update the images using rsync.

[Here's a good tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/howto_linux_systemimager) to make it really easy.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would install ssh on the finished notebook and then boot the other one from livecd. LiveCD should contain ssh and rsync at least.
2. Then save MBR from the first:

   `dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/sda_mbr bs=512 count=1`
3. And restore it on the second

   `scp [ip_of_first_nb]:/tmp/sda_mbr /tmp`

   `dd if=/tmp/sda_mbr of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1`
4. And reload known partitions on /sda

   `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda`
5. and rsync the root partition

   `rsync -avzx -e ssh [ip_of_first_nb]:/ /`

DD of whole disc would take lot of time to save-copy-restore, since it'll copy blank place on disc.

**Be aware of the fact, that `dd` will replace your current partition layout and bootloader!!**